# How to manage many powershell terminal in single tabular window

Tags: powershell, terminal, windows-10

I have more than 15 Powershell terminals running to launch some particular service. Each of these terminals is running spring boot applications in different ports. I have to constantly check logs from those terminals. It is very inconvenient to use those terminals individually. I wonder is there any tool or way to group all Powershell terminals so that each of this terminal will be a tab just like Google Chrome browser can have any tab and each tab for different websites. How can I manage them wisely and smartly?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

Comment: really nice one. thx

Comment: If you're not on Windows10 you could try [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that  Windows Terminal is the one. It is wonderful. Thanks to Luuk for the suggestion.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/get-started